# How to convert a MS Word 2003 file that contains a screen capture into an image?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, microsoft-word-2003

My MS word file has a screen shot. I want to convert it into an image file and upload it on stackoverflow.com. Right now I am downloading GIMP for Windows XP. Can I do it easily through GIMP?. How do I do the conversion?

---

Somehow MSPaint seems to be missing from my computer

Comment: You can just save that image.

Comment: @AkshatMittal how ?I only have a .doc file.

Comment: Do you have word installed? If yes, that What version?

Comment: @AkshatMittal yes I do.

Comment: Which Version??

Comment: @Subhra Couldn't you just copy it into Paint and save that?

Comment: @Bob He dosen't have Paint

Comment: Whoops, I missed that @AkshatMittal... There's a good chance `mspaint.exe` is still there, and just the shortcut is missing.

Comment: @Bob No, the Paint app has exe file as `mspaint.exe`

Comment: @AkshatMittal Yes, I was just checking that (the comment got submitted accidentally). In any case, any image editor where you can paste an image from the clipboard should work.

Comment: @bob that's True but not so good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As You said you have MS Word installed, then Open the doc file, Right click the Image and select Save as Picture. Simple

As you have word 2003 installed, So, here is the solution.

Using the following steps for Word 2000, Word 2002/XP, or Word 2003:

1. Open the document in Word.
2. Click File from the Standard Toolbar.
3. Click Save As.
4. Specify your Save in location.
5. Select Web Page (*.htm; *.html) from the Save as type drop-down menu, as shown in Figure A. Make sure you choose Web Page (*.htm; *.html) and not Single File Web Page (*.mht; *.mhtml). 
   [image: IMG1]
6. Click Save.

**Word will create a .htm file and folder containing the embedded images. You can now have the Images.**

***[source](http://www.techrepublic.com/photos/save-images-in-microsoft-word-documents-as-separate-files/206113?seq=1)***

Comment: I do not see that option on right clicking .That is my main problem.

Comment: What all options (File Types) do you get in the Save As Menu for saving ?

Comment: I get .rtf,.doc,.xml,.dot,.html etc ...no image files. I have just installed GIMP. Do you know how do that using GIMP ?

Comment: Good, I am editing the Answer

Comment: Here it goes. This is the Solution.

Comment: I already did that using GIMP.But yes this also could have  been a solution. Thanks for the help. Actually you can see the image here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311697/suggest-the-most-optimized-fastest-way-of-loading-a-100-column-x-1000-rows-ta

Comment: Couldn't you display the picture/document on the screen, then, using gimp, take a screenshot, of the screenshot, and then save it to the hard drive?   Or.. if it makes more sense.. open a word document, and paste it there... you should be able to handle it from that point.

Comment: That would also be possible, but with this process, You will get the ORIGINAL Resolution and this seams to be a bit better.